# urllib: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I am trying to make an API call where I pass a file in the header

```
import urllib.request

headers = {'files[]': open('File.sql','rb')}
datagen ={}

request = urllib.request.Request('https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert', datagen, headers)

response1 = urllib.request.urlopen(request) 
# Error : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

response2 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert', datagen, headers)
#Error: 'dict' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The error I am retrieving is:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It works with Request for a simple GET call. I think something is wrong eithe request may be

Comment: Check the edited question. response2 ; #Error: 'dict' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: The 3rd parameter to `urlopen` is supposed to be an integer, `[timeout, ]*` is supposed to be an integer. Try removing the headers part.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example](https://www.rebasedata.com/python-read-sql) you've based your code on is antiquated, and in any case, you've translated into something else – you can't read a file into a *header*; the example's `poster` library returns a body stream and the associated headers, which is not what you're doing.

Here's how you'd do the equivalent POST with the popular [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import requests

resp = requests.post(
    'https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert',
    files={'files[]': open('file.sql', 'rb')},
)
resp.raise_for_status()
with open('/tmp/output.zip', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(resp.content)
```

(If you're expecting a large output you can't buffer into memory, look into `requests`'s `stream=True` mode.)

Or, alternately (and maybe preferably, these days), you could use [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/):

```
import httpx

with httpx.Client() as c:
    resp = c.post(
        "https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert",
        files={"files[]": open("file.sql", "rb")},
    )
    resp.raise_for_status()
    with open("/tmp/output.zip", "wb") as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
```